# Convert one string into many

Tags: java, string

How do I convert this single string: `"CO2+H2O"`

Into two different strings: `"CO2"` and `"H2O"`

and alternatively; make a loop so that whenever there's a plus, it will make a separate string:
e.g. for `"C+H2O+Q+Z3P+N2"` into `"C"` `"H2O"` `"Q"` `"Z3P"` `"N2"`

Comment: No need for a loop. use `split` with a regular expression.

Answer (score 2):

Using `public String[] split(String regex)` you can have all your substrings in an array.

```
String[] many = "CO2+H2O".split("\\+");
```

Once done you can loop over the array to process  each separate string

```
for(String one : many){
    System.out.println(one);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use String.split

```
String s = "C+H2O+Q+Z3P+N2";
String[] separated = s.split("\\+");
```

Comment: You need to escape `+`, i.e. `s.split("\\+");`

Comment: What about if you just wanted to do one and make it into another string?
e.g. "CO2+H2O" 
into: c = "CO2"

Comment: `s.split(...)[0]` to take the first element. Or `s.substring(0, s.indexOf('+'))`. (Both assume there is a `+` in the string; the first assumes the string is not all `+`s).

Answer (score 0):

You could use StringTokenizer:

```
String str = "C+H2O+Q+Z3P+N2";
StringTokenizer tokenizer= new StringTokenizer(str, "+");
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
        list.add(tokenizer.nextToken());
}
```

More info here:
[StringTokenizer example](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-stringtokenizer-example/)

Comment: How would you convert one object at a time to a string using this method?

Comment: What do you mean by one object at a time? Do you mean that you could have many Strings like "C+H2O+Q+Z3P+N2"? Or do you want to store  your new String values from tokenizer in other data structure (not in ArrayList)? Basically tokenizer.nextToken() returns String value